# Microsoft Exchange Transport Agent

Tags: c#, connection-string, exchange-server

I am building a transport agent for Microsoft Exchange server. The logic I have implemented so far works. Now, I want to store some of the variables in DB. I have opted for a repository pattern and when I try to extract a connection string from App.Config file I am receiving a NullReference Exception:

```
public class ConfigRepository : IConfigRepository, IDisposable
{
    private string configString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["citadelEAPEntities"].ConnectionString;
    // private string configString = "..."; here I tried to write the string directly .
    private string configValProc = "[dbo].[GetConfigValue]";
    private SqlConnection connection;

    public ConfigRepository()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(configString);
    }

    // other logic and implementation of interfaces
}
```

The same class is implemented in a test console app, which works fine (with the same connection string stored in the same manner in the app.config file). 
I cannot understand the reason for this exception. The transporter agent class instantiates a ConfigRepository class within a 'using' statement and the moment it reaches the constructor function upon the initialization of the connection string variable via config manager an exception gets thrown. Obviously when I use the connection string in a hard coded manner everything works just fine.

Is the transporter agent assembly somehow limited while referencing other assemblies (such as System.Configuration) ? Just weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport Agents run under the security context of NetworkService so its most likely that it doesn't have enough rights to load the assembly from the location your referencing it from. If you use something like process monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon your should be able track the process etc.